# Run animation on items inside loop one by one - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, settimeout, phaser-framework

I have an array like this:

```
var myArray = array(
   [0] => array(
       [0]=>{reel:2, location:1}
       [1]=>{reel:1, location:7}
   )
   [1] => array(
       [0]=>{reel:2, location:1}
       [1]=>{reel:3, location:6}
       [2]=>{reel:1, location:5}
   )
);
```

Need to put animation on each item from the above array therefore I am running a for loop on the array and calling animation function inside it.

```
for(var j=0; j < myArray.length; j++){ 
     animateItems(myArray[j]);
}


function animateItems(params){
   for(var p = 0; p < params.length; p++){
           params[p].reelEl.animations.add('highlightAnim');
           params[p].reelEl.animations.play('highlightAnim', 13, true);
    }
}
```

But the issue is that all items animation is happening at the same time but I need them to be one after the other.

Tried to do something like this but didn't help:

```
for(var j=0; j < myArray.length; j++){ 
     (function() {
        setTimeout(function(){animateItems(myArray[j]);}, j * 1000);
     })(j);
}
```

Seems I am doing something wrong. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You dont add parameter (j) in IIFE signature (so in your example it still **j** variable from `for` loop):

```
for(var j=0; j < myArray.length; j++){ 
 (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function(){animateItems(myArray[index]);}, index * 1000);
 })(j);
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of wait a time to complete the animation. You could use a callback `onAnimationComplete` and perform a recursive function. Something like:

```
   var myArray = [[{ reel: 2, location: 1 },
    { reel: 1, location: 7 }],
    [{ reel: 2, location: 1 },
    { reel: 3, location: 6 },
    { reel: 1, location: 5 }]];

    function animation(x = 0, z = 0) {
      console.log(myArray[x][z])
      myArray[x][z].reelEl.animations.add('highlightAnim');
      myArray[x][z].reelEl.animations.play('highlightAnim', 13, true);

      myArray[x][z].reelEl.onComplete.add(function () { 
         if (myArray[x][z + 1]) {
              z++
            } else if (myArray[x + 1]) {
              x++
              z = 0;
            }else{
              return;
            }                
     animation(x, z) }, this);//<-- recursive callback     
    }

    animation();
```

Comment: as long as now you modified animation funcnion, what you suppose to use as `element` please?

Comment: @aidadev I made a mistake, I've updated the code, but it's just like a pseudo code, the idea is to call one animation after previous is completed. To do this we call the same function in onComplete callback